# setInterval() not working after window.open() in Android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Just a little problem: I'm making a Hybrid app developed in angular with Cordova but when I use a `setInterval()` function after a `$window.open()` the `setInterval` stops working, but in Chrome, it's working (but it's normal, the new window is opened in a new tab).

This is the an extract of my code :

```
$http.post(url)
.success(function(result, status) {
    var windowWithings = $window.open(result.res);
    var intervalVerif = $window.setInterval(function (){
        $http.get(url)
        .success(function(result) {
            windowWithings.close();
            $window.cancelInterval(intervalVerif);
        })
        .error(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }, 2000);
})
.error(function(error, status) {
    console.log(status);
});
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

What I searching to do with the `setInterval` is to check each 2000 ms if the server got the information from the new window I have opened. If it's ok for the server I close the window to come back to the previous.

When I say it's not working I want to say that the new window doesn't close but if I change the code with an alert I can see sometimes an alert before the new window had the time to open but nothing after

For Chrome, I just say that if I open the Angular app in Chrome on my laptop it's working, but if I launch my Android app created with Cordova it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't really get what it is you are trying to accomplish, you should be a bit more specific. "the setInterval stop working" -- what is not working, and what is it you are expecting. "but in chrome it's working" -- if you use other browser it works?

Comment: I edit my post for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

please use $timeout and add '$timeout' in injection parameters

```
$timeout(function (){
  $http.get(url)
  .success(function(result) {
    windowWithings.close();
    $window.cancelInterval(intervalVerif);
  })
  .error(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });, 2000);
```

Comment: It's not a timeout that I want to do but an interval (see my edit on my original post). I tried before to use $interval but the problem was the same with it.